# How do I calculate weight percent of BaCl2

Tags: everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, ionic-compounds, composition

A $\pu{0.1036 g}$ sample containing only $\ce{BaCl2}$ and $\ce{NaCl}$ is dissolved in $\pu{50 mL}$ of distilled water. Titrating with $\pu{0.07916 M}$ $\ce{AgNO3}$ requires $\pu{19.46 mL}$ to reach the end point. What is the weight percent of $\ce{BaCl2}$ in the sample?
(Molar mass of $\ce{BaCl2} = \pu{208.232 g mol-1}$ and Molar mass of $\ce{NaCl} = \pu{58.4425 g mol-1}$)

The way I did it was ;

0.1036g of sample contained 266.6745 Molar mass of $\ce{BaCl2}$ and $\ce{NaCl}$

i.e. 0.1036g of sample= 266.6745 of substance

x g = 208.232 of $\ce{BaCl2}$ only

x g=(0.1036*208.232)/266.6745

=0.08089 g

Where 0.08089 g is the mass of $\ce{BaCl2}$ present in the sample.

Weight % = (0.08089/0.1036)*100%

= 78%

I don't know if I'm correct.

what is the correct solution to the assignment please?

Comment: Doesn’t this statement of yours raise a red flag: “From my own solution : 0.1036g of sample contained 266.6745mol/L of BaCl2 and NaCl”?

Comment: Hint: Using the densities and molar masses, pure NaCl has a “molarity” of 37.13 mol/L and barium chloride’s “molarity” is 18.52 mol/L. A mixture of the two would have intermediate “molarity”.

Comment: Your approach is incorrect. Set up two equations with two different data. Remember you precipitate all $\ce{Cl-}$ in the solution as $\ce{AgCl}$.

Comment: Use algebra for solving it. Choose two unknowns : $x$ for the number of moles $\ce{NaCl}$ and $y$ for the number of moles $\ce{BaCl2}$. Now $x + 2y$ is the number of moles of $\ce{Cl-}$ ions. And it is also equal to the product Volume $\ce{AgNO3}$ times concentration of $\ce{AgNO3}$. this gives you a first equation. The second equation is related to the masses. The mass of $\ce{NaCl}$ is equal to $x$ times $58.4 g$. The mass of $\ce{BaCl2}$ is equal to $y$ times $208.2 g$. This gives the $2$nd equation. Try to write them properly, and solve the system of two equations and two unknowns. Go !

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are the amount of $\ce{BaCl2}$ and $\ce{NaCl}$ in $\pu{mol}$, respectively in original mixture. Thus the mass of $\ce{BaCl2}$ in the mixture is $208.232x$ and that of $\ce{NaCl}$ is $58.4425y$, both in $\pu{g}$. Thus,

$$208.232x + 58.4425y = 0.1036 \tag1$$

Now, the the amount of $\ce{Cl-}$ ions in original mixture is $2x+y$ in $\pu{mol}$. And all of them are precipitated by $\ce{AgNO3}$ according to:

$$\ce{Cl- + AgNO3 -> AgCl + NO3-}$$

Therefore, mole ratio of $\ce{AgNO3 : Cl-}$ needed is $1:1$. Since total $\ce{Cl-}$ in the reaction is $2x+y$, The amount of $\ce{AgNO3}$ used $(\pu{0.07916 mol L-1} \times \pu{19.46 \times 10^{-3} L} = \pu{1.540 \times 10^{-3} mol})$ is equal to $2x+y$. Thus,

$$2x+y = 1.540 \times 10^{-3} \tag2$$

Now, you have two equations for two unknowns, so you can solve them easily.

First, $(1) - (2) \times 58.4425$ gives

$$208.232x - 58.4425 \times 2x = 0.1036 - 58.4425 \times 1.540 \times 10^{-3} = 0.01360$$

$$\therefore \ x = \frac{0.01360}{91.347} = 1.489 \times 10^{-4}$$

Apply this value in the equation $(2)$, and you get:

$$y = 1.540 \times 10^{-3} - 2x = 1.540 \times 10^{-3} - 2 \times 1.489 \times 10^{-4} = 1.242 \times 10^{-3} $$

Thus, the mass of $\ce{BaCl2} = 208.232x = \pu{0.0310 g}$ and the mass of $\ce{NaCl} = 58.4425y = \pu{0.0726 g}$.

Thus, weight percent of $\ce{BaCl2} = \frac{0.0310}{0.0310 + 0.0726} \times 100 = \frac{0.0310}{0.1036} \times 100 = 29.92\%$

Comment: (+1) Glad to see I got the same answer!